# Como anexar objectos con ObjectOutputStream sin borrar contenido fichero?

Tags: java

La cuestion es esa, no me anexa los objetos creados a los que contiene ya el fichero, sino que me los sobreescribe... alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Os dejo el codigo que hace la funcion de guardar los objetos.

```
public static void EscriureFitxer(String nom,String cognom1,String cognom2,String dni,File FILE_NAME,ArrayList<Alumne> list){
                Alumne a = new Alumne (nom,cognom1,cognom2,dni);
                list.add(a);
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = null;
                try {
                    objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME));
                    objectOutput.writeObject(list);

                    System.out.println("S'ha generat el fitxer " + FILE_NAME);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(objectOutput != null) {
                        try {
                objectOutput.close();
                        } catch (IOException ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                }
}


public static void LlegirFitxer(File FILE_NAME){
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;

                try {
                    objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));

                    ArrayList<Alumne> list = (ArrayList<Alumne>) objectInput.readObject();
                    for(int u=0;u<list.size();++u) {
                        System.out.println(u + " --> " + list.get(u));
                    }

                    objectInput.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                if(objectInput != null) {
            try {
                        objectInput.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
                }
                }       
}
```

Comment: La solución la encuentras en este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355908/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-a%c3%b1adir-datos-a-un-fichero-de-objetos-binario-sin-sobrescribir-los-da/356058#356058). Solo debías crear tu propia clase, en la cual herede de `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, creo que he entendido lo que estás haciendo después de darle vueltas un rato (y haber respondido erróneamente antes).

Tal como veo que tienes el programa escrito, sin ver cómo haces las llamadas a los métodos, llamas a la función que escribe `EscriureFitxer` con los parámetros que tiene un Alumne, la ruta de un File donde escribe y un ArrayList de Alumne que escribes en el fichero. 
Visto lo que haces en el método, podrías pasarle directamente un objeto Alumne y luego añadírselo a la lista, o pasar directamente la lista con el Alumno añadido, pero eso no viene al caso.

Tal como lo tienes ahora mismo lo que hace es sobreescribir los datos que había porque, como te habían dicho, para hacer que cuando escriba no escriba encima de lo que había, en el constructor de FileOutputStream hay que meterle un segundo parámetro que es true, para que haga append a lo que había.

Si le añado el parámetro true a mi me funciona correctamente el añadir, ojo, sólo el añadir.

Ahora bien, antes en tu programa tenías esto: `ArrayList<Alumne> list = (ArrayList<Alumne>) objectInput.readObject();`
Eso lee un objeto, que en este caso es una lista, pero solo lee uno. Aunque el programa funcionase, solo leería la primera lista que añades, no las demás.

Lo que no sé es si tu idea es tener una sola lista en tu fichero o tener más de una, pero tal como lo tienes planteado ahora mismo tendrías muchas, pero sólo estás leyendo una.

Si quisieras tener solo una lista, no tienes que hacer que el fichero vaya añadiendo cosas nuevas, si no sobre escribir la lista que ya había con la nueva, pero para eso en el método de escritura primero tendrías que recuperar la lista y añadir el nuevo elemento.

Voy a interpretar que quieres ir añadiendo nuevas listas para comentar un fallo que veo que quizás es importante puntualizar.

Si en el constructor del `FileOutputStream` ponemos el segundo parámetro para que sobreescriba new `FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME, true)` vamos a tener que hacer algo para poder leer todas las listas que se hayan almacenado. Algo como esto:

```
Object actual = null;
ArrayList<Alumne> lista = null;
while((actual = objectInput.readObject()) != null) {
    lista = (ArrayList<Alumne>) actual;
    for (int u = 0; u < lista.size(); ++u) {
       System.out.println(u + " --> " + lista.get(u).getNom());
    }
}
```

Esto iteraría sobre todas las listas que haya hasta que no haya más. Por cierto, habría que controlar `EOFException`para cuando llegue al final del fichero.

Pero hay un problema con esto. Cuando se escribe un fichero con objetos se escribe una cabecera al inicio. Si escribes una vez e intentas leer no habrá fallo. El programa ve la cabecera y leerá todo perfectamente. Si intentas añadir algo nuevo al fichero escribirá después de lo ya existente una nueva cabecera. Cuando intentes leer usará la primera cabecera y leerá el primer valor, pero cuando intentes leer el segundo, escrito con otra cabecera, lanzará un [error por cabecera corrupta](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

la solución a este problema es, que cada vez que quieras escribir algo nuevo crees un nuevo lo primero que hay que hacer es crear un canal de lectura y de escritura e ir leyendo y escribiendo todo (sin cerrar el canal de escritura) y cuando llegues al final escribir lo nuevo y entonces cerrar los canales.

Como sospecho que tu intención es que haya una sola lista en tu fichero te propongo este método para escribir:

```
public static void EscribirFichero(String nom, String cognom1,
    String cognom2, String dni, File FILE_NAME) {

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;
    ArrayList<Alumne> list = new ArrayList<Alumne>();
    try {
        if(FILE_NAME.exists()) {
            objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
            list = (ArrayList<Alumne>) objectInput.readObject();
        }

        Alumne a = new Alumne(nom, cognom1, cognom2, dni);
        list.add(a);

        objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME));
        objectOutput.writeObject(list);

        System.out.println("Se ha generado el fichero " + FILE_NAME);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (objectOutput != null) {
            try {
                objectOutput.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Leerá la lista que hubiera, le añadirá el elemento nuevo y escribirá en el fichero la nueva lista.

Para leer he usado este método, ligeramente modificado:

```
public static void LeerFichero(File FILE_NAME) {
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;

    try {
        objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));

        Object actual = null;
        ArrayList<Alumne> lista = null;
        while((actual = objectInput.readObject()) != null) {
            lista = (ArrayList<Alumne>) actual;
            for (int u = 0; u < lista.size(); ++u) {
                System.out.println(u + " --> " + lista.get(u).getNom());
            }
        }

        objectInput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(EOFException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (objectInput != null) {
            try {
                objectInput.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda esta vez :)

Comment: Hola, en lugar de agregar otra respuesta, edita la que realizaste primeramente, evitar realizar multiples repuestas . Revisar [answer]

Answer (score 1):

La clase [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) ofrece un constructor con dos parámetros: [`FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-) donde el segundo argumento `boolean append` indica si quieres re escribir el archivo o continuar la escritura desde el final. Agrega el parámetro en `true` en tu código:

```
objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME, true));
```

Adicionalmente, si trabajas con Java 7, puedes hacer uso del `try-with-resources` y evitar llamar al método close manualmente:

```
//el bloque try va a cerrar el stream por ti
try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(
         new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME, true))) {
    objectOutput.writeObject(list);
    System.out.println("S'ha generat el fitxer " + FILE_NAME);
    //adicionalmente, el bloque catch puede contener más de un tipo de excepción separadas por pipe 
} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Esto ya lo he probado luiggi y la serializacion en java no soporta el boolean true, y por lo tanto al crear un nuevo objeto y introducirlo en el fichero borra el contenido del fichero y pone el ultimo objeto creado, en canvio con parametro true, lo que hace es ignorar el ultimo objeto creado y te mostrara en el fichero el primer objeto que habias creado con anterioridad.

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre porque el método `writeObject` no respeta lo que hay anteriormente escrito en el fichero.
Puedes crearte un método para leer el archivo antes de sobreescribirlo:

```
public String leeArchivo (String ruta) {

    File file = new File(ruta);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String contenido="";

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            // Convertir a char para guardarlo
            contenido += Character.toString((char) content));
        }
        return contenido;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Y en tu método que escribe en el archivo, escribe el resultado de leer el fichero, antes de escribir lo nuevo.

```
String contenido = leeArchivo(FILE_NAME);
objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME));
objectOutput.writeBytes(contenido);
objectOutput.writeObject(list);
```

Comment: Hola cnbandicoot he estado implementando el ejemplo que has puesto como respuesta pero decirte que me esta dando problemas, cuando inserto un objeto dentro del fichero no hay problema pero en el momento de querer leerlo me da error y pienso que es porque tu has trabajado con String y yo estoy haciendo uso de una arraylist para almacenar mas de un objeto y grabarlo en el fichero, tienes idea como se podria modificarse el ejemplo que me has pasado para trabajar con arraylist y no suceda este error? gracias

Comment: Mira a ver si con la actualización que he añadido al código te sirve. He añadido la línea: `objectOutput.writeBytes(contenido);` y la linea: `objectOutput.writeObject(list);`

Comment: at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java‌​:1365) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:‌​373) at cat.iesjoaquimmir.alumnesapp.views.console.Application.Llegi‌​rFitxer(Application.‌​java:231) at cat.iesjoaquimmir.alumnesapp.views.console.Application.main(‌​Application.java:192‌​)


Este es el error que me sale ahora, he añadido el metodo llegirFitxer(); para aver si hay que modificar algo mas