# ¿Se puede modificar un boolean en un fichero binario serializable?

Tags: java, poo, object, serialización, file

según he leído en algunas webs no se puede modificar el objeto, pero si cambiar al valor de una variable booleana. La cuestión es que lo hago de la siguiente manera y no muestra ningún error, pero cuando hago la modificación e imprimo el objeto no cambia nada. ¿Es posible modificarlo?

public void ExisteMoto(String fichero, String NombreMoto) {

```
    try {   
        MotObjectOutputStream objectOS = new MotObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero,true)); 
        ObjectInputStream objectIS = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fichero));

        Object ObjMotos = objectIS.readObject();

        while (ObjMotos != null) {

            if (ObjMotos instanceof Moto) {
                String ObjNombre = (((Moto) ObjMotos).getNombre());
                if (ObNombrej.equals(NombreMoto)) { //Comprobar nombre existe

                    ((Moto) ObjMotos).setExiste(false);
                    objectOS.writeObject(ObjMotos);         
                    objectIS.close();   
                }else {
                }        
                ObjMotos = objectIS.readObject();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Se ha cambiado el estado"); 
        objectIS.close();       
    }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: ¿Qué clase es MotObjectOutputStream ? No me suena haberla usado nunca.

Comment: Es una clase creada por mi @Alejandro

Comment: Qué has modificado de esa clase? Supongo que extiende de ObjectOutputStream, pero necesito saber si has modificado algo. Con respecto a eso puedo darte una respuesta a tu problema

Comment: Correcto, la clase extiende de ObjectOutputStream. No he hecho ninguna otra modificación @Alejandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he probado tu código, pero diría que el problema radica en que estás intentando serializar / deserializar objetos en el mismo fichero al mismo tiempo.

Prueba a dividir la función en estos pasos:

1. Abrir fichero, deserializar objetos, cerrar fichero.
2. Modificar estado de los objetos (`setExiste(false)`).
3. Abrir fichero, serializar objetos, cerrar fichero.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! Voy a probar :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, vamos a ir por partes para no liarnos.

Con respecto a la clase que has creado `MotObjectOutputStream` que extiende de `ObjectOutputStream`, si no le has cambiado nada, usa directamente la clase padre. Es solo una recomendación, sólo te serviría si en un futuro tienes previsto modificar algo, cosa que dudo. Pero ese no es el problema aquí.

Lo primero que hay que entender es como funcionan los canales de escritura y lectura de ficheros. En este caso estás usando `new FileOutputStream(fichero,true)` inicializar uno. Si vas a la [documentación sobre ese constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) verás que lo que está diciendo es que al pasarle un true como segundo parámetro le estás diciendo que cualquier cosa que escribas mediante ese canal será añadido al final del fichero.
Eso quiere decir que cualquier cosa que estés intentando escribir se escribirá después de los objetos que ya haya.

Con lo cual, si cuando quieres comprobar si se ha modificado el primer objeto que encuentra siempre te va a decir que no, porque lo que ha hecho ha sido escribir un objeto nuevo y añadirlo al final.

Los ficheros binarios con objetos tienen una desventaja, si lo que quieres es modificar uno, lo normal es que crees un fichero nuevo y vayas escribiendo todo lo que encuentras y cuando encuentras el objeto que quieres modificar, no escribes ese sino el modificado.

Además, escribir un objeto, cerrar el canal y volver a abrirlo para volver a escribir otro objeto puede provocar fallos a la hora de leer el fichero.
En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45694/como-anexar-objectos-con-objectoutputstream-sin-borrar-contenido-fichero/125594#125594) ya expliqué algo similar.

Espero te haya sido de ayuda. Si tienes alguna duda por aquí estaré.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, entre tu respuesta y la anterior, lo he solucionado ;)