# ¿Cómo puedo añadir datos a un fichero de objetos binario sin sobrescribir los datos?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo mantener los objetos introducidos en un fichero binario de objetos?

Este es el código que tengo hecho hasta ahora:

```java
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String nom;
String apellido;
String barrio;
String DNI;
String FILENAME = "clientes.data";

File file = new File (FILENAME);
ObjectOutputStream output = null;
try 
{
    if (!file.exists()) 
        output = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (FILENAME));
    else 
        output = (new FileOutputStream (FILENAME,));
        output.writeObject(peluqueria);
        System.out.println("Operación de escritura terminada");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally 
{
    if (output != null)
    {
        try 
        {
            output.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `FileOutputStream` tiene un [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) con dos parámetros:

```java
public FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
```

Si el segundo parámetro recibe un `true`, los datos se agregarán al final del archivo y no al principio. Sin embargo, esta no seria la solución.

Lo comprobamos de esta manera:

```java
ObjectOutputStream output = null;
try 
{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream(FILENAME, true));
    output.writeObject(peluqueria);
    System.out.println("Operación de escritura terminada");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally 
{
    if (output != null)
    {
        try 
        {
            output.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Imagina que el código de arriba está en un método llamado `write` y luego lo invocas tres veces. ¿Qué pasará? Pues la información serializada se agregará al final del archivo. Sin embargo, el problema viene cuando tratemos de deserializar el objeto por segunda vez, ya que la máquina virtual de Java nos lanzará la siguiente excepción:

```java
Exception int thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header
```

Esto se debe porque el constructor parametrizado de la clase [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream)) crea un encabezado (el constructor invoca implícitamente al método [writeStreamHeader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeStreamHeader())) de información y la agrega al archivo cada vez que queramos escribir en el y ese es el problema, que este encabezado solo se debe crear únicamente una vez (al principio del archivo), de lo contrario, no podremos deserializar más de un objeto.

**Solución:** Toca crear nuestra propia clase
`ObjectOutputStream`, en la cual tendremos que
sobrescribir el método `writeStreamHeader` (ya que este
método es el encargado de crear la cabecera).

Entonces, el algoritmo quedaría así:

**1.-** Nuestra clase personalizada debe heredar de `ObjectOutputStream`.

**2.-** Crearemos un constructor parametrizado en la cual recibirá la ruta donde se encuentre el archivo.

**3.-** Invocaremos al constructor parametrizado de la clase base y posteriormente llamaremos a un método (el nombre de este método será `createFile`), en la cual retornará un objeto de tipo `FileOutputStream`.

**4.-** En la definición del método `createFile`, verificamos si el archivo realmente existe, si es verdadero, asignamos el valor de `true` a una variable booleana y por último, creamos una instancia de tipo `FileOutputStream`.

El cuarto paso se debe cumplir antes que el constructor de la clase base invoque a `writeStreamHeader`, ya que solo crearemos la cabecera cuando el **archivo no exista** (esto se debe porque el archivo solo debe tener únicamente una cabecera), de lo contrario, no habrá la necesidad de invocar al método `writeStreamHeader` de la clase `ObjectOutputStream`.

La definición de nuestra clase personalizada quedaría así en Java:

```java
class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream
{
    /* Para saber si el archivo existe o no. */
    private static boolean isExist;

    public MyObjectOutputStream(String path) throws IOException
    {
        /* Invocamos al constructor de la clase ObjectOutputStream */
        super(createFile(path));
    }

    private static FileOutputStream createFile(String path) throws IOException
    {
        /* Si el archivo existe.. */
        if(new File(path).exists())
            isExist = true;
        return new FileOutputStream(path, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
    {
        /* Si el archivo no existe.. */
        if(!isExist)
            super.writeStreamHeader();
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Si quieres saber porque el método `createFile` es estática, te recomiendo leer esto: [No se puede hacer referencia a "X" antes de que se haya llamado Supertype Constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cannot-reference-x-before-supertype-constructor-error).

La forma de usarlo sería de esta manera:

```java
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String nom;
String apellido;
String barrio;
String DNI;
String FILENAME = "clientes.data";

MyObjectOutputStream output = null;
try 
{
    output = new MyObjectOutputStream(FILENAME);
    output.writeObject(peluqueria);
    System.out.println("Operación de escritura terminada");
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally 
{
    if (output != null)
    {
        try 
        {
            output.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A partir de Java 7 podemos hacer uso de bloques
[ARM](https://riptutorial.com/es/java/example/1581/la-declaracion-de-prueba-con-recursos). Esta característica de Java nos evita estar cerrando los recursos manualmente.

El código ahora quedaría así:

```java
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String nom;
String apellido;
String barrio;
String DNI;
String FILENAME = "clientes.data";

try(MyObjectOutputStream output = new MyObjectOutputStream(FILENAME))
{
    output.writeObject(peluqueria);
    System.out.println("Operación de escritura terminada");
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Conclusión:**

Con nuestra solución logramos que el encabezado solo se cree únicamente una vez y adicionalmente, no tendremos problemas al momento de leer el archivo, porque solo tendrá un encabezado al principio.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Mañana por la mañana lo pruebo

Comment: @JosepGiner ¡De nada! Si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides de aceptarla como la "correcta".

Answer (score 0):

En Java se suele usar una bandera (un boolean) para indicar si el archivo se va a sobreescribir (false) o si va a hacer un append (true)

Prueba con:

```
 output = (new FileOutputStream (FILENAME, true));
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Mañana por la mañana lo pruebo